# Restore the checkbox value in React Tab component

Tags: reactjs

I have created simple tab component in React.

Here, I'm having content with checkbox. In Tab1, I'm selecting some content and navigating to Tab 2. If I click again Tab 1, there is no checkbox got selected which I clicked earlier. Please help me, how to store the selected checkbox value and how to retrieve that again when I'm clicking Tab 1. Thank you

Sample code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-gagarin-npix45

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are re-rendering the tab.
Every time you change the  active tab you are doing this:

```
const TabContent = ({ id, activeTab, children }) => {
  return activeTab === id ? <div className="TabContent">{children}</div> : null;
};
```

To fix this, you should store the status of the checkbox checked on the parent component of tabs.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, you are right. Because of huge content in my real application, so every time I'm rendering the content.

Comment: I dont know if you need a really custom tabs component, but you can save time and logic using bootstrap or material tabs. Glad to help :)

Comment: Okay, let me try that. Thank you once again.